# Partial Linux GUI install on Chromebook was interrupted. How do I undo all that was done and start over?

Tags: linux, installation, chromebook

I got a phone call and bumped a key and have no idea where I am and want to undo all that is done so far, go to back to bare bones penguin so that I can start over.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you just tried reinstalling it.  It may well just overwrite the existing install

Comment: I'll try that. I'll need to find a different method, though. The one I was using had the very last part covered up by You Tube notifications when the video was paused to copy the commands and I couldn't read them.